# How i can get access from Parent ViewController to child PageViewController

Tags: swift

I have `OnboardingViewController` which contains `containerView`. My `containerView` - its a `OnboardingPageViewController`.

How i can get access on my `OnboardingViewController` to `OnboardingPageViewController`?

For example from `OnboardingViewController` i want send action to `OnboardingPageViewController`. I have my example code, but it doesnt work

[image]

My `OnboardingViewController`

```
class OnboardingViewController:  BaseViewController, Storyboarded {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    
    var infoRegisterRefferenceVC : OnboardingPageViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    func saveContrainerViewRefference(vc:OnboardingPageViewController){

        self.infoRegisterRefferenceVC = vc

    }
    
    
    @IBAction func previewAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // send action to OnboardingPageViewController
        infoRegisterRefferenceVC?.next()
    }
    
}
```

this is my `OnboardingPageViewController`

```
class OnboardingPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    

    lazy var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
        
        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc1")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc2")
        let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc3")
        let vc4 = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc4")
        let vc5 = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc5")
        
        return [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5]
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        
         
        let signUpControllerParent = self.parent as? OnboardingViewController
        signUpControllerParent?.saveContrainerViewRefference(vc: self)
        
        if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first {
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func next() {
// example test code
        self.setViewControllers([viewControllerList[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
    
    
    
}
```

My code doesnt work because on this place

```
let signUpControllerParent = self.parent as? OnboardingViewController
    signUpControllerParent?.saveContrainerViewRefference(vc: self)
```

`signUpControllerParent` is nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How i can get access on my OnboardingViewController to OnboardingPageViewController?

It is your `children.first`. You will also need to cast down to OnboardingPageViewController in all likelihood.

As for your actual code, (1) the communication goes the opposite way from what your question asks for, and (2) `viewDidLoad` is too soon.